# Adding sections in the 'Pages' post type

Tags: plugins, order, post-type, management

I'm wondering if there is a way to add titles or nested groups to the pages post type. A website of ours have an enormous amount of pages so we want to order the pages in (preferably) groups/categories without changing the permalink structure.

Now:

```
- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3
```

to:

```
Normal pages:
 - Page 1

Landing pages:
 - Page 2
 - Page 3
```

I can't find a plugin or a way to develop this into the WP backend.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just add categories to your pages?  https://thewphosting.com/add-categories-tags-pages-wordpress/

Comment: @TonyDjukic Yeah, I've actually did do this for now. It's not the most clean option but it'll do I guess, thank you!